# Problem with if statement in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display an edit button for each row if logged in as admin.

XML:

```
<vendors>
   <vendor id="1" name="Microsoft" description="1" odd="1"></vendor>
   <vendor id="2" name="Apple" description="1"></vendor>
   <vendor id="3" name="Google" description="1" odd="1"></vendor>
   <security ADMIN="1"></security>
</vendors>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="vendors">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <xsl:if test="/vendors/security/@ADMIN = '1'">
          <td></td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="vendor">
          <tr>
            <xsl:if test="@odd = '1'">
              <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="/vendors/security/@ADMIN = '1'">
              <th><a href="#"><img src='edit.gif'></a></th>
            </xsl:if>
            <td title='Name'><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
            <td title='Description'><xsl:value-of select="@description" /></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Right now this doesn't work. When logged in as admin (@ADMIN = "1"), everything works. When logged in with @ADMIN = "", none of the table cells are displayed (only empty rows).

Comment: minro issue but the img tag should be self closing to be valid xml

Comment: I've run this through the microsoft xml parser and it performs as expected.  What XSLT parser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart a problem in the output document (not closed **img** tag and not open **div**) the XSLT shown is correct and should show the cells Name/Description even when **@ADMIN** is "" (tested using Saxon).

You might also compare integers directly, as follows:

```
test="/vendors/security/@ADMIN = 1"
```

Comment: Yes, it does work and I have no idea why it didn't before when I tried it many times in different browsers. Thanks.

Comment: It was the `<img>` tag! The `<div>` was just missing in my modified example, but when I closed the `<img>` tag it started working.

Comment: What's weird is that the `<img>` tag works without closing outside of the if statement.

Comment: It's always good practice close tags, even if HTML allows you to leave some of them open. That's no relevant from the point of view of a browser, while it's _really_ relevant from the point of view of an XSLT processor. Finally, I suspect your XSLT processor is buggy.